# VBA User Defined Function not working in Mac Excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

I wrote a user-defined function in Excel 2016 for Mac. The function itself works; I called it within VBA in a new Subroutine and it worked fine. But when I call it from the sheet, it does nothing.

```
    Function isMultipleOf5(myInput As Integer) As Boolean

    Dim result As Double

    result = myInput Mod 5

    If result = 0 Then
        isMultipleOf5 = True
    Else
        isMultipleOf5 = False
    End If

    End Function
```

Comment: Without the code, it will be quite hard to tell you what's wrong with it specifically. Best guess: it does something UDFs aren't allowed to do.

Comment: Code is attached. It worked fine on my classmates' Windows computers.

Comment: Don't know vba on Macs, but I'd try changing myInput to a variant. At least on PCs, that's the default data type for UDF parameters.

Comment: @RichHolton didn't work

Comment: I don't have a Mac to test this on, but there is nothing apparent in this code that should be a problem. The issues usually with Mac OS compatibility are fairly well documented and limited to some fringe cases and additional libraries which aren't compatible (i.e., `"Scripting.Runtime"`, etc.)

Comment: Does it "do nothing" or does it return an error in the calling cell? Have you put a breakpoint in to ensure the function is being called? Then step through the code line by line to see if you can determine any failure point?

Comment: @DavidZemens "invalid name error" #NAME? in the cell I try calling the function

Comment: @Nate, that error suggests the function is not accessible, so either you've a typo in the cell formula, or the function is defined in either different sheet's code module, or in the Workbook module. In order that the function may be accessible from all worksheets, it should be placed in a standard code module.

Comment: @DavidZemens that was it!! I was placing the code under "Microsoft Excel Objects", and putting the code in ThisWorkbook or Sheet1 doesn't allow function to work. Instead, you must right click on Microsoft Excel Objects -> Insert -> Module -> place the code in the new blank area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I was placing the code under "Microsoft Excel Objects", and putting the code in ThisWorkbook or Sheet1 doesn't allow the function to work. Instead, you must right-click on Microsoft Excel Objects -> Insert -> Module -> place the code in the new blank area.

Answer (score 1):

It also depends on location of the inserted Module.

If Module containing the function is inserted into the workbook you run your formula, it's fine to call the function directly from the spreadsheet. However, if Module is inserted in personal makro workbook, then the function has to be called from the spreadsheet as follows `=PERSONAL.XLSB!function()`